# How to load a pytorch grid in wandb?

Tags: pytorch, wandb

I'm training a network using pytorch (no lightning or other modules) and I'm using W&B to monitor the training metrics. During the epochs, I'm also loading some images that allow me to keep track of the learning process. Since I had an error "Fail to allocate bitmap" when I was using matplotlib to create figures and subplots which were then loaded to W&B, I want to use an alternative. In particular, I want to use the `make_grid` function from `torchvision.utils`. I tried to load the object `grid = make_grid(my_tensor_list, nrows, padding)` with `wandb.log({'mygrid': grid})` but the problem is that W&B displays a big question mark, probably because it can not recognize the object. Does any of you know how to load a pytorch grid in W&B? That would be very helpful. I have already tried to look for an answer but I couldn't find anything. Usually, figures are created with matplotlib.

Thanks for you help.